# fetching external APIs with React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

this code *works* if I click save on Visual Studio code. But when I refresh the page in the browser (new call to the APIs) it gives me this error:

"TypeError: Cannot read property 'collections' of undefined"

```
import React from 'react'

export default function Apitest() {

const [shows, setShows] = React.useState([]);

var myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append("Authorization", "Basic xxxxxx3456789");

var requestOptions = {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: myHeaders,
  redirect: 'follow'
};

React.useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://api.vhx.tv/collections", requestOptions)
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(result => setShows(JSON.parse(result)))
    .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
}, [])


    return (
        <div>
            <h1>{shows._embedded.collections[0].name} is a great show!</h1>
        </div>
    )
}
```

I think that the problem is that I need to make an asynchronous call.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is settings the `shows` variable initially as an `array` and then assigning an `object` to it after the `asynchronous call` in `useEffect`.

Since the `shows` are present in the `collections` array in the `_embedded` object, you might want to store the `collections` array in `shows` like this:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
fetch("https://api.vhx.tv/collections", requestOptions)
.then(response => response.text())
.then(result => setShows([...JSON.parse(result)._embedded.collections]))
.catch(error => console.log('error', error));
}, []);
```

And when displaying the `show`, you might wanna do this:

```
return (
    <div>
        <h1>{shows.length && shows[0].name} is a great show!</h1>
    </div>
)
```